# using several to-infinitive subsequently

Tags: infinitives

Can we say: "I want to learn to drive my car to go to my workplace to earn money"?   Is it appropriate to use several infinitive with to subsequently?

Answer (score 2):

The first two instances of ***to*** in OP's example are "infinitive markers" (for ***learn*** and ***drive*** (the other two are short for ***in order to***).

But there's nothing about English syntax that prevents us chaining more that two "true infinitives" together. For example,...

> *You need **to want to learn to drive***

...is perfectly natural English. Note that I could extend that utterance with ***...to pass your driving test***, but ***to*** there would be a preposition introducing an "adverbial clause of purpose", not another "infinitive marker" (and ***pass*** is an "unmarked infinitive").

Answer (score 1):

> *I want to learn to drive my car to go to my workplace to earn money.*

It's fine syntactically, but a succession of four infinitival clauses is stylistically inelegant.

You could simplify and say "I want to learn to drive so I can go to work by car".

Comment: I may be wrong, but it seems to me that although there are indeed 4 consecutive "infinitival" elements, the 3rd & 4th occurrences of ***to*** aren't actually infinitive markers. They're just short forms of ***in order to***, which could alternatively be expressed by something like ***so that I may*** without needing to include ***to*** at all before the unmarked infinitive that follows.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I take "in order" to be a compound preposition (the two words are inseparable here) with the _to_ infinitival clauses as purpose adjuncts. [link](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_order).

Comment: This is where I get confused. That Wiktionary link says ***to*** is "synonymous" with ***in order***, but that deconstruction doesn't really work for me. I can choose to say *I eat **to** live* or *I eat **in order to** live*, but I can't *eat **in order** live*. I'd be quite happy with the idea that "in order **to**" is a  compound preposition, but I guess that's not what you meant.

Comment: To be precise, the compound prep "in order" takes _to_-infintival clauses as its complement, and the whole PP "in order + infinitival clause then serves as a purpose adjunct. But the OP's example is simply two catenative clauses followed by two _to_-infinitival clauses serving as purpose adjuncts.

Comment: I can't say I really understand that - the implication seems to be that *s + v + to-infinitive* can be understood as *s + v **in order, so as** to-infinitive*, with the highlighted element being optional. Which may be so, but it seems an odd way of looking at things to me. Whatever - at least we seem to be in agreement that the first two infinitives are different to the second two in OP's example, which was my main concern. It does occur to me there's potential ambiguity as to whether and where the "catenative" elements end and the "purpose adjuncts" start (both of which can occur repeatedly).